# Image manipulation is visible only in some part of the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, codeblocks

I am using OpenCV in codeblocks to manipulate image pixel's value. 
The code must make the image completely black but it is doing something as shown

```
for(int i=0; i<src.cols; i++)
for(int j=0; j<src.rows; j++)
src.at<uchar>(j,i) = 0;
```

[Here is the resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIheu.jpg)

But when i print the pixel values, they all are zero
Someone, please help!!

Comment: In your image only the first third is black. That indicates that `uchar` is not the right type. `uchar` is an 8 bit integer, but your image might be 24 bit. That could be a reason for getting a false offset during the loop.

Comment: is it a 24 bit color (or 3 channel) image? Then use .at<cv::Vec3b> instead of uchar. As a hint fir tge future: Using the row in the outer loop is much more efficient because of fewer cache misses.

Comment: Thanks guys, using <cv::Vec3b> worked....!!!! Thanx a lot